# LDAP User Store WSO2 ESB - Admin Username

Tags: ldap, esb, wso2, wso2-esb

Hello I need some help to set up the LDAP user store for WSO2 ESB:
I have my ldap host: `ldap://my.domain.ac.uk:389`
the basedn `dc=my,dc=domain,dc=ac,dc=uk`
username password: `Name Surname` `mypassword`

I can't figure out how to succesfully configure the `user-mgt.xml` file of the WSO2 ESB, I get "

```
LDAPUserStoreManager Carbon cannot function without an Admin Username
```

`DefaultRealm Cannot create org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPUserStoreManager . Error is : null`"

my configuration for ldap is:

```
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPUserStoreManager">
            <Property name="ReadOnly">true</Property>
            <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://my.domain.ac.uk:389</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionName">cn=Name Surname,ou=Users,dc=my,dc=domain,dc=ac,dc=uk</Property>
            <Property name="ConnectionPassword">mypassword</Property>
            <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=Users,dc=my,dc=domain,dc=ac,dc=uk</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=sAMAccountName)</Property>
            <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
            <Property name="ReadLDAPGroups">false</Property>
            <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=Users,dc=my,dc=domain,dc=ac,dc=uk</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
            <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">uid</Property>
            <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
            <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
        <Property name="ReplaceEscapeCharactersAtUserLogin">true</Property>
        </UserStoreManager>
```

any suggestion?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In user-mgt.xml there's following config element,

```
<AdminUser>
    <UserName>admin</UserName>
    <Password>admin</Password>
</AdminUser>
```

Make sure you have a user called admin in your LDAP. Or provide a username that exist in LDAP. HTH.

Comment: Already tried that with different combinations,but did not work thanks anyway.

Comment: @nuvio just to make sure, did you try following this guide for setting up the user store? - http://wso2.org/project/solutions/identity/3.2.3/docs/user-core/admin_guide.html#LDAP

Comment: yes I did,. At the end I have implemented an authentication mediator for my Proxies which works great. thank you again

Answer (score 0):

do you have the uid attribute in your AD? I see this problem before, and it happen because the ESB with this config cannot find the user you specified in the:

```
<AdminUser>
    <UserName>admin</UserName>
    <Password>admin</Password>
</AdminUser>
```

your connection name use cn = .....  and you try to search using uid !!! this is the right config? maybe you can post the ldap schema.

Answer (score 0):

You must include the following:

```
<UserManager>
    <Realm>
    <Configuration>
            <AdminRole>LDAP_ADMIN_GROUP</AdminRole>
            <AdminUser>
                 <UserName>LDAP_USER</UserName>
                 <Password></Password>
            </AdminUser>
        <EveryOneRoleName></EveryOneRoleName> <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
        <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</Property>
        <Property name="MultiTenantRealmConfigBuilder">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.config.multitenancy.SimpleRealmConfigBuilder</Property>
    </Configuration>
```

Where LDAP_ADMIN_GROUP must be a group that exists in the LDAP server, and will have assigned admin privileges in WSO2 server.

LDAP_USER must belong to the aforementioned LDAP_ADMIN_GROUP. You don't need to provide the password, can be left empty.

Also make sure the Filter and SearchBase you configure are correct, and the users and groups are within that range.

You can find more details here:

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB450/Configuring+External+User+Stores